# Why Does Setting Meteor Template Data Context Replace Parent Data Context?

Tags: html, meteor, spacebars

I want to pass an argument to a template I'm invoking in a loop:

```
<template name="show_people">
    <div class="panel-body">
       {{#each people}}
           <div>
                {{>person }}
                {{>person doing="running up the hill"}}
           </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="person">
     <h3>{{name}} is {{doing}}</h3>
</template>
```

The helper javascript:

```
Template.show_people.helpers({
    people: function() { return [{ name: 'Jack' },{ name: 'Jill' }]; }
});
```

Adding the 'doing' argument to the template seems to clobber the context of the loop item.  Here's what I'm getting back:

```
Jack is
is running up the hill
Jill is
is running up the hill
```

I would like the person template to be able to access both the argument and the context.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hack : pass a name argument to your template that is copied from the parent context.

```
{{> person name=name doing="running up the hill"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer solves your problem but does not give an explanation as to why you are experiencing the issue that you are. If you take a look at [this article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) under the Template Includes section header, you will find the reason why.

Basically, just inside of your `{{#each people}}{{/each}}` code block, the data context of any contained templates will be the list item within the `people` collection. In the case of your first two code snippets, the two data contexts for the two instances of `people` would be `{name: "Jack"}` and `{name: "Jill"}`, which is the reason why you are seeing `Jack is` and `Jill is` being printed out for these two template instances. The data context does not contain a `doing` parameter.

When you reference your `person` template in the second way (`{{> person doing='running up the hill'`), the data context for that template instance is reset and a whole new data context only with the specified parameters is created. For both instances of your `person` template, the data context would be `{doing: "running up the hill"}`, which is why you are seeing `is running up the hill` being printed out twice.

So as you can see, the data context setting is not additive, but rather, it is exclusive. Either the data context is the parent data context for the block of code where a given template reference appears, or it is an overridden data context consisting of all of the parameters defined in the template reference. The reason why the accepted answer works is because you are combining both data contexts into a single overridden data context to be used in the `person` template.